# How to use intreq with browserify to compress requires paths down to integers

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

There is a project called [intreq](https://github.com/substack/intreq) by [substack](https://github.com/substack) (the author of [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)). It says it can compress requires paths down to integers.

For example it can convert this code:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports = function (n) { return n * 111 }

},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
var bar = require('./bar.js');
module.exports = function (n) { return n * bar(1) };

},{"./bar.js":1}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
var foo = require('./foo.js');

console.log(foo(5));

},{"./foo.js":2}]},{},[3])
```

to this:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports = function (n) { return n * 111 }


},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
var bar = require(1);
module.exports = function (n) { return n * bar(1) };
},{"1":1}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
var foo = require(1);

console.log(foo(5));
},{"1":2}]},{},[3])
```

This seems really good and is really handy when using with long require paths, but there is no docs about using it with browserify. I'm wondering how is it possible to use intreq with browserify API to generate output with integer requires instead of full paths.

I'm expecting something like this:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var intreq = require('intreq');
var b = browserify();
b.add('./browser/main.js');
b.bundle()
 .pipe(intreq())
 .pipe(process.stdout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [unpathify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/unpathify), it's based on [intreq](https://github.com/substack/intreq)

Comment: Noting that it has been deprecated in favor of Substack's [bundle-collapser](https://github.com/substack/bundle-collapser).